# Tools for software synthesis, preferably Python

Tags: python, code-generation

I'm looking for tools/frameworks/modules for software synthesis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis), preferably a Python module. My use case is to synthesize a simple (Python) function, extrapolating from a few examples of argument and value pairs. For example, generate code of a Python function `f`, which satisfies these assertions:

```
assert(f(3, 1) == 3)
assert(f(2, 2) == 2)
assert(f(1, 3) == 1)
assert(f(4, 4) == 4)
assert(f(8, 5) == 9)
assert(f(7, 6) == 9)
assert(f(9, 7) == 9)
assert(f(5, 8) == 9)
assert(f(6, 9) == 9)
```

The expected result is equivalent to:

```
def f(a, b):
  return a if b <= 4 else 9
```

It is acceptable that synthetic `f` is correct only for small integral arguments, e.g. `in range(10)`

Comment: Why isn't the expected function implemented like `if a==3 and b==1: return 3 elif a==2 and b==2: return 2 elif ... else return 9`? If you have N examples, I can generate you a function with roughly N lines of code.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Generated function is supposed to extrapolate the domain of examples, otherwise it's not contributing anything new.

Comment: From a math standpoint, I'd say it's not worth it. You give me 9 samples of a function and I can find an arbitrary number of functions which satisfy those 9 points but go on very differently.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, in general there is an infinite number of such functions, but depending on program synthesis algorithm, constraints can be imposed, e.g. grammar or maximum complexity. Less formally, I'm looking for a simple and short function.